# ¿Cómo doy formato a un numero en html/php (o javascript)?

Tags: php, html, funciones

Buenas tardes

Tengo el campo de texto donde ingreso un número, por ejemplo 1000000. Por cuestiones estéticas, el usuario quiere verlo como 1,000,000.
Usé una función de javascript pero necesito que sólo cambie el formato (la forma de mostrarse)sin cambiar el número en sí.
Leí sobre la función de PHP "number format", pero no se cómo usarla.

Esto lo voy a aplicar a todos los campos numéricos que tengo

Anexo código

```
                            <td>
                            <input id="txtImporteCargo1" data-msg="Debe ingresar un valor." 
                            data-rule="required" type="number" 
                            class="importe-cargo form-control">
                            <div class="validation error"></div>
                            </td>
```

Agradezco orientación.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar number_format

**number_format — Formatear un número con los millares agrupados**

Aqui unos ejemplos desde [El sitio Oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php)

Ejemplo #1 Ejemplo de number_format()

Por ejemplo, la notación francesa suele utilizar dos decimales, una coma (',') como separador decimal y el espacio (' ') como separador de millares. Esto consigue esto mediante las siguientes líneas:

```
<?php

$número = 1234.56;

  $decimales = number_format($número,2);
 //1,234.56

// notación inglesa (por defecto)
$número_formato_inglés = number_format($número);
// 1,235

// notación francesa
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($número, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$número = 1234.5678;

// notación inglesa sin separador de millares
$english_format_number = number_format($número, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57



?>
```

Comment: Gracias Luis Fernando. Lo intenté implementar como 
$txtImporteCargo1 = number_format($txtImporteCargo1);
Pero no me funciona porque no se como implementarlo correctamente

Comment: Pues solo has esto: $txtImporteCargo1 = number_format($txtImporteCargo1, 2); El numero 2 indica los decimales despues del punto

Comment: Le agregué los tres parámetros restantes y aún así no funciona:

Comment: sube el codigo de lo que intentas, para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí un ejemplo de como sería pero sin el type "number" por que cuando es number no admite comas entre los números, a menos que hagas un artificio.

**script.js + index.html**

```js
$("#txtImporteCargo1").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <td>
            <input id="txtImporteCargo1" data-msg="Debe ingresar un valor." 
            data-rule="required" type="" 
            class="importe-cargo form-control">
            <div class="validation error"></div>
        </td>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarse la molestia de contestar.

Le comento:

Estos campos a los que necesito darles formato, los utilizo en otras funciones JS para sumarse entre sí; por esa razón no los puedo convertir con una función JS, pues a la hora de sumarlos, me dan más problema.
Y Por eso es que requiero alguna forma de editar unicamente el formato, pero como ya comenté, intenté con la función de PHP y en ningún navegador me funciona...

Agradezco su comprensión